# Get name to my buttons in QMessage box

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

I would like put a name for my buttons in this code. It is about a QMessageBox.

```
if(QMessageBox::Ok == QMessageBox(
     QMessageBox::Question,
     "Confirmar registro.",
     "¿Desea confirmar guardar los datos?",
     QMessageBox::Ok,
     tr("Aceptar") | QMessageBox::Cancel ,
     tr("Cancelar")).exec()
   )
```

Comment: Google is your friend https://wiki.qt.io/Custom_QMessageBox_Buttons http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28739-QMessageBox-Text-in-the-buttons

Answer (score 2):

`QPushButton * QMessageBox::addButton(const QString & text, ButtonRole role)` creates a button with the given text.

Answer (score 1):

Almost straight from the [docs](https://wiki.qt.io/Custom_QMessageBox_Buttons) on Custom message box.

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("Confirmar registro.");
msgBox.setInformativeText("¿Desea confirmar guardar los datos?");
QAbstractButton *acceptButton = msgBox.addButton("Aceptar", QMessageBox::YesRole);
QAbstractButton *cancelButton = msgBox.addButton("Cancelar", QMessageBox::NoRole);
msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
msgBox.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add you custom [`QAbstractButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html) at `QMessageBox` using [`addButton()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#addButton-1) method.

Example of usage:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText(trUtf8("Confirmar registro."));
msgBox.setInformativeText("¿Desea confirmar guardar los datos?");
QAbstractButton *myYesButton = msgBox.addButton(trUtf8("Aceptar"), QMessageBox::AcceptRole);
QAbstractButton *myNoButton = msgBox.addButton(trUtf8("Cancelar"), QMessageBox::NoRole);
msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
msgBox.exec();

if(msgBox.clickedButton() == myNoButton)
{
    return;
}
```